# Removing commas (,) from certain text part

Tags: regex, replace

I have file which contains thousands and every line has such text part as example:

```
,Home > Opto-electronics > LED > Standard LED, Multicolour,2226,
```

So they start with **,Home >** and end with **,combinationofnumber,**

I need to replace in this position betweem (in this case Opto-electronics > LED > Standard LED, Multicolour) commas with nothing that is would look like:

```
,Home > Opto-electronics > LED > Standard LED Multicolour,2226,
```

how should look my replacing regex?

Comment: What is the output rquired for above input?
Is it `Home > Opto-electronics > LED > Standard LED Multicolour,2226`?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use

```
text.replaceAll("(,)(.*)(,)", "$2")
```

which returns the replaced string. **text** is the input

This removes commas at beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

To match it exactly you can use

```
/(?<=^,)(.*)(?=,$)/
```

or more solid

```
/^.*,([^,]*,\d*),.*$/
```

.

.

for replacing you could try it this way (in php for example)

```
var $result = preg_replace( '/^.*,([^,]*,\d*),.*$/', '\1', $inputline );
```

or in Java

```
inputline.replace( '/^.*,([^,]*,\d*),.*$/', '$1' );
```